# What type of classifier is Naive Bayes?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, classification, naive-bayes

I am currently studying the Naive Bayes method (a classification method) and **I am having quite some trouble classifying it as a hard or soft classifier**. Below follows a quick introduction on the method and my thoughts about this question.

One of the disadvantages of Bayesian Decision Theory is the fact that we need to manipulate multivariate density functions, which can lead to some problems. This is why Naive Bayes is so important: in this method, we have a simplification of the problem where we assume that the independent variables $x_1 , \dots , x_D$ are independent between them. Therefore,

$$ P(C_k \, | \,x ) = \frac{P(C_k) \cdot f(x \, | \, C_k )}{f(x)} = \frac{P(C_k)\cdot \prod_{i=1}^D f(x_d \, | \, C_k)}{\prod_{i=1}^D f(x_d)}.$$

With this in mind, we can easily adapt the minimum error Bayes' decision rule to our Naive Bayes method, which yields

$$ \text{ Decide } C_j \text{ if } P(C_j)\prod_{i=1}^D f(x_d \, | \, C_j) = \max_{k = 1,\dots,M} P(C_k)\prod_{i=1}^D f( x \, | \, C_k), $$
where $M$ represents the total number of groups in our problem.

**My problem.** How can I figure if Naive Bayes is a hard or a soft classifier? As far as I know, we define a hard classifier as being a classifier that directly estimates a group, i.e., given an observation $\mathbb x$, our classifier tells us that $\mathbb x$ belongs to some class $C$ of our problem. On the other hand, we say a classifier is a soft classifier if it estimates the *a posteriori* probabilites.

In my mind, Naive Bayes does both. For example, If I give some observation $\mathbb x$ to the Naive Bayes, it is going to return me which class $\mathbb x$ should belong to. At the same time, it also estimates *a posteriori* probabilities (this is what we calculate to decide which class $\mathbb x$ belongs to). So how can I decide if Naive Bayes is a hard or soft classifier?

**Are my general concepts about hard and soft classifiers wrong or incomplete?**

Thanks for any help in advance!